# How to find item matching keywords with different weights?

Tags: sql, sql-like, keyword

I'm trying to make an SQL request that find the best items matching a request.

I have keywords that have different weights (very important keyword, important keyword, etc.) And I want to sort result order by the score.

My table: ID, field, value.

Field can be "productName" or "productdescription" and value is the text.

I don't know how to add the weight to each keyword, and to compute the score of each item.

I'm just using for now the `LIKE` syntax:

```
SELECT id FROM products
WHERE (field='productname'
     AND value LIKE '%KEYWORD1%'
     AND value LIKE ‘%KEYWORD2% … )
OR (field='productdescription'
AND value LIKE '%KEYWORD1%' AND value LIKE '%KEYWORD2%'..)
```

I know that the syntax `MATCH-AGAINST` could be used there, but how to add the weights to the keywords?

Answer (score 1):

The best answer to this question is not to treat strings as lists of keywords!  SQL has this really great data structure for lists.  It is called a *table*, not a *column*.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  I think the best method is a "derived table" with the keyword and weight, and then logic like this:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM products p JOIN
     (SELECT 'KEYWORD1' as kw, 1 as weight UNION ALL
      SELECT 'KEYWORD2' as kw, 10 as weight UNION ALL
      SELECT 'KEYWORD3' as kw, 10 as weight
     ) kw     
     ON (p.field IN ('productname', 'productdescription') AND
         p.value LIKE CONCAT('%', kw.kw, '%')
        ) 
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY SUM(weight) DESC;
```